# Custom commands like title and authors

Tags: titles

When I use

```
\title{My title}
\quthor{Myself}
```

I can later access these two parameters in the class file by using

```
\@title and \@quthor
```

Is there a way to define my own custom fields, like

```
\cost{This book costs loads}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\reviewer{This person revewed the book}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult, just look up the definition of `\title`.

cmd input

```
latexdef -s \title
```

return

```
% latex.ltx, line 7370:
\DeclareRobustCommand\title[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}
```

So we can write code like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\mycmd[1]{\gdef\@mycmd{#1}}
\newcommand{\test}{These are my orders! \@mycmd}
\makeatother

\mycmd{123}

\begin{document}
  \test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using `\newcommand{tag}{reference}` option to define such custom fields as in:

```
\newcommand{\cost}{This book costs loads}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{My subtitle}
\newcommand{\reviewer}{This person reviewed the book}
```

For instance, when you use `\cost`, it will replace and print "This book costs loads" on your document. I hope that help.

Comment: Not really the solution for the asked problem. We want to assign "This book costs loads" to `\cost` in the preamble so we can use it like `\author` etc.

Comment: My answer does exactly what you said. You can use `\cost` like so. I just defined a new command without a parameter instead of `\newcommand{\cost}[1]{#1}`. Could you elaborate on your objection so that I can either improve my answer, if I can, or even delete it if it is way off-topic?